# How to change the background color of the ads banner in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, google-ads-api

I use the library 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-ads: 19.1.0' for advertising, I create a banner as follows: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive so that it always turned out to be the full width of the screen and everything works well, but sometimes black lines appear [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRBLo.jpg)

please tell me how can I remove them? I tried transparent styles and setting the background color,

android: theme = "@ style / TranslucentTheme"
android: background = "@ color / transparent"

In xml and through the code, and nothing helps.

Comment: This black background is only for test ads. it will not be visible in live ads.

Comment: @AlphaOne Thank you very much, for some reason this is not mentioned anywhere